# How to declare mutable Object in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any option to use Mutable Object in Flutter ?

I would like to get help on this

Answer (score 0):

I am puzzled. By definition, all the objects are mutable in Flutter, unless you explicitely use unmodifiable constructors like `Map.unmodifiable`, or `const`. But otherwise, you are should be able to modify anything.